# API Gateway rejecting requests having spanish characters (á , í)

Tags: tomcat8, xerces

Below is my API Gateway mapping template for Integration request. This mapping template doesn't seem to allow spanish characters.

Example - John á O'Smíth
[Sample XML which has spanish characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrkPd.jpg)

[Current API Gateway Integration Request Mapping Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRNpi.jpg)

I have tried the below configuration adding charset to the content type , but that doesn't work too.

[Modified Mapping Template to allow charset UTF 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LE6cr.jpg)

Getting below error while testing via API gateway -

[Error while testing via API gateway](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KShAe.jpg)

Comment: The error seems to be from an Apache Tomcat web server... presumably, this is a resource you are proxying to, rather than API Gateway itself.

Comment: Also, doesn't valid XML require the character `'` to be escaped as either `&apos;` or `&#39;`?  Perhaps this is the problem, rather than the other characters.

Comment: Michael -  '  has been escaped using the mapping template -->  {"body": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.body).replaceAll("\\'","'")"}

Comment: Single Quote works just fine , since we have escaped it. Issue is with Spanish character support.

Comment: Issue seems to be with tomcat and xerces. My application is deployed on tomcat and it used to work fine when it was on jboss.